# Serve static bundle.js from remote file via Express as your static file server

Tags: reactjs, express, webserver, static-files

I am trying to serve a *React front-end* (bundle.js) with an *Express back-end.*

The repositories exist independently of one another. The static React bundle file is hosted remotely on a separate file server (nginx).

I want Express to be both the file server that serves the static file, as well as the application server responsible for the api endpoints.

I know about `express.static()` method, however, that would only work if the bundle file is in the same directory as the back-end. But in my case the repos are separate. How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE:**

So the only solution to this is to have the *build* folder included in the deployed Express-backend. I simply had Webpack spit out the *bundle.js* to the back-end repo, and am  not using `express.static()` method to successfully serve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this

`app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/dist')));`

the frontend folder is not in the same folder as server.js but in the parent folder
I'm doing this in my MEAN app and it works

Comment: Yes but its still in the same repo. My "frontend" directory is in a separate repo hosted remotely

Comment: in this case you don't have to serve your frontend app with express, you can serve it using nginx and it still consume the API